# Text copied into body shows up in edit but not in view

Tags: 8

When I type out text by hand into the body of an "article" it shows up correctly in preview and all views.

If I copy text from some other source like a word doc, HTML doc, even a .txt file; everything after the first line break is not showing up. I've tried reformatting the text, moving it to different programs, changing the "text format", editing it in source view and no matter what I do it won't show up in either preview or saved/published.

Is there some known issue with hidden characters copying over and causing issues?  Or is this some weird Drupal 8 bug?

I'm running core 8.0.2.

Comment: it might be the WYSIWYG issue, check with WYSIWYG editor disabled